# How can I jump to the place on the page where there is a form error using Parsley.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js, meteor

I'm using Parsley.js to do form validation. I have a form that is larger than one screen vertically. I'd like to take the user to the field that is in error when they submit the form. Any idea how I might scroll to or jump to that part of the page if the user isn't already seeing that error field?

I'm sure there is a way to do this in jquery or javascript, and I'm ok with either of those, but I wasn't sure if there might also be a Meteor way to do this.

Comment: Use [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) to scroll to the first instance of class `parsley-error` on submit